# Problem with event listener in google maps (with fusion tables)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to use google maps inside a jquery mobile app. The map has a fusion table layer, the layer loads properly, and the click listener gets called, but the value given to the callback function is null. I need to use values associated with the marker clicked.

Setting the layer and adding the event listener.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
     query: {
         select: 'Address',
         from: table_id
     }
});

// map is an instance of google.maps.Map
layer.setMap(map)

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
     console.log(e);
     $.mobile.changePage(...);
});
```

Am I using the addListener properly?

Relevant [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapsEventListener).

Relevant [example](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/attachmentText?id=150&aid=-5541269104385006157&name=change_infowindow_content.html&token=a1e7244fd1c5200a739d5a8ae2ece5c9).

Comment: Yes I am. console.log(e) prints 'null' and any attempt to reference a value that "should" be in e (e.row['Address'].value) Gives a "can't read property 'row' of null".

Comment: Code works properly. A restarted my computer for other reasons and the code works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works properly. Restarted my computer and the problem appears to have disappeared. (Clearing a cache perhaps?)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue until I allowed the Fusion Table Layer do display the infowindow,

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'location',
      from: tableid
    },
//    options: {suppressInfoWindows: true}, // don't suppress or you lose the event 
    map: map
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Think even if you use {suppressInfoWindows: true} it should work but after remove browser cache.